# how to set weights manually to the input features from the default weights in keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

i am getting the default weights from each epoch.for the existing weights i have to replace the previous weights with manually selected weights.how to set weights for each epoch ?

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 100, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 8))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 50, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 5))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1 , activation = 'sigmoid'))
print_weights = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda batch, logs: print(classifier.layers[0].get_weights()))
classifier.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics = ['accuracy'])
classifier.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=100,nb_epoch=10,validation_data=(x_test, y_test),callbacks = [print_weights])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `train_on_batch` in a loop instead of `fit` and `layer.set_weights(weights)` to set the weights by hand.